# Meteor issue with recaptcha Google : verifyCaptcha is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor, recaptcha

I use a package (appshore:recaptcha) to use the Google recaptcha system and I have trouble using it. I have an error that say `verifyCaptcha is not a function`.

I call my method from client side :

```
//get the captcha data
var captchaData = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();

var resultCaptcha = Utils.captchaCheck(captchaData);
```

And I defined it in a Utils section in server side :

```
captchaCheck: function (captchaData) {
    var ip = "0.0.0.0";

    if(Meteor.isServer) {
        if(!this.connection.clientAddress)
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Server Error: You must be connected.");
        else
            ip = this.connection.clientAddress;
    }

    var verifyCaptchaResponse = reCAPTCHA.verifyCaptcha(ip, captchaData);

    if (!verifyCaptchaResponse.success) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('422', 'reCAPTCHA Failed: ' + verifyCaptchaResponse.error);
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But when I submit my form I have the error above mentioned...

Comment: Have you verified your `reCAPTCHA` object has that method?

Comment: Yes, the object has the method and I follow the doc of the package...